# nodejs : TypeError: mongo.collection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to nodejs getting errors. i want to insert in collection of mongodb database. please give me any suitable solution or guide me about this.

TypeError: mongo.collection is not a function. 
    at Server. (D:\taha\MultiChannelChatApp-master\MultiChannelChatApp-master\routes\RegUser.js:30:34) 
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
url = require('url');


// var db = require('../db');


var mongo = require( '../db_mongo' );


http.createServer(function(request, response){
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;

var setval = {username: query.name, email: query.email, password: query.pass};
//     db.query('INSERT INTO users  SET ?', setval, function (err, res) {
//         if (err)
//             throw err;
//
// });


if (mongo) {console.log("mongo  connected here ss");}

var userCollection =   mongo.collection('users');

userCollection.insert((setval, function(err, result) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    res.write("<p>Product inserted:</p>");
    res.end("<p>" + result[0].make + " " + result[0].model + "</p>");
}));


    // db.collection('users').insertOne( {
    //     username: query.name, email: query.email, password: query.pass
    // }, function(err, result) {
    //     assert.equal(err, null);
    //     console.log("Inserted a document into users");
    //     callback();
    // });
// };

// insertDocument(db, function() {
// });




}).listen(8001);
```

**db_mongo**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url_db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

exports.connectdb = function (callback) {

module.exports = MongoClient.connect(url_db, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    }
    if (!err) {
        console.log('Connection established to', url_db);
        return db;
    }
});
}
module.exports = exports;
```

Comment: this line is causing the issue: `var userCollection =   mongo.collection('users');`. What's inside the file  `'../db_mongo'` ?

Comment: check new edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line here is probably causing you problems:

`module.exports = exports;`

remove it and it should fix your error.

Generally, you'll assign to either `module.exports` or `exports`, but not both unless you do them inline.

`exports` is if you want to export named functions, `module.exports` is if you want the whole module to be a function or object you define.

Sometimes, folks (especially in older modules) would overwrite both like:

```
module.exports = exports = function(){ /* whatever */ }
```

but that's a lot less common anymore.

Also, your whole file is burying the export inside of an exported function for some reason.  Note you're doing:

exports.connectdb = function(callback) { /* stuff */}

where inside /*stuff*/ you're again calling module.exports...

If you were do do:

`console.log(require('../db_mongo'));` in the calling code, you'd probably see that all it's got is the connectdb function attached to the exports object.

Also, it's not clear that you understand the asynchronous style of node, from the calling code you have in your first block of code.

If your db_mongo.js is trying to just wrap the driver's connection so that you can put your connection string in, fine, but you still need to treat it as an asynchronous function afterward.

db_mongo could look something like this:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url_db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

module.exports = function(callback) { 
   MongoClient.connect(url_db, callback); 
});
```

And then the calling code would be:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
url = require('url');

var mongo = require( '../db_mongo' );


http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;

    var setval = {username: query.name, email: query.email, password: query.pass};

    // The ../db_mongo.js file is now exporting a function that takes a callback; usage of the database has to happen inside that callback
    mongo(function(err, db){
        var userCollection =   db.collection('users');

        userCollection.insert(setval, function(err, result) {
            if(err) { res.send(err);  }
            res.write("<p>Product inserted:</p>");
            res.end("<p>" + result[0].make + " " + result[0].model + "</p>");
        });
    });


}).listen(8001);
```

Comment: again same error : TypeError: mongo.collection is not a function

Comment: Sorry, was on mobile before, just realized how much of a mess that file is.  One second, I'll edit.

Comment: even mongo object is not null it is showing that mongo.collection is not a function

Comment: Right, the object isn't null, it's the stuff you exported from the other file.  It's just not what you think it is.  See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks very near to resolve butdo you know this error ??

(node:16504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: no write ops were included in the batch

Comment: Just like it says, a Promise was rejected and you didn't handle it.  I don't see you using Promises in your posted code yet, but the pattern there is anytime you have a promise you'd do, `aPromise.then(function(){ /* handle success*/}).catch(function(){ /* handle an error or rejection */});`.

Comment: what will be the actual reason for this ?... why not inserting simple insert it is

Comment: Inserting is simple, you just have to follow the documentation and understand your environment.  Also, most folks find it easier to use Mongoose than the native mongodb driver, as the latter is very low-level.

Comment: I actually noticed that when I copied and pasted your code I included a `throw err` line.  You can't do that in a callback, you need to instead handle the error through logging and response.  See my update.

Comment: sir i think mongo(function is not calling because it is not going inside this function ... i have console.log before and after of it